# mkpasswd on Centos 7 does not support -m flag

Tags: linux, centos, password, encryption, centos7

I cannot find how to install `grub-crypt` either.

How can I generate SHA512 pass hashes on Centos 7?

*Edit:* I was actually trying to look up how to generate hashes with an adjustable number of rounds. I had done this before but couldn't remember how I did it last time.

Comment: What are these mkpassword and grub-crypt things you are referring to? I can't find any such things.

Comment: Are you kidding me? First two google searches http://serverfault.com/questions/330069/how-to-create-an-sha-512-hashed-password-for-shadow http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52108/how-to-create-sha512-password-hashes-on-command-line

Comment: No, I'm not kidding. If you use some nonstandard utility that many people won't be familiar with, you should have some respect for the people you're asking to help you and explain it.

Comment: I apologize for the rudeness. It's very frustrating because I used to know how to do this before but now I can't get this to work.

Comment: No problem. - I've marked this as a duplicate, since your question about mkpasswd is the same, and the answer you chose is also present there. I don't know what question you have about grub-crypt, but you should ask a new question if you still need to do so.

Comment: I actually found the same blog page that I found 2 years ago, which contained the name of the file I had to edit to get what I needed. I will change my answer... It's technically not really a dupe but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I can use [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76337/12497) with the way to generate a random hash given in a comment.

The page I was looking for (which I didn't know I was looking for) was [this page](https://blog.myconan.net/posts/3567). It contains information that allows me to configure the # of rounds of hashing to do for passwords. Then in order to generate new passwords, I simply set the password for a user as root, and read out the hash from `/etc/shadow`.